# Installshield write a user defined property to the registry

Tags: windows, installation, installshield-2010

I am making an installer where I have defined my own installer property. I want to store this property in the registry. As this property is only needed by the installer, I thought that the best location to store it would be:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{PRODUCT CODE}.
```

I use Installshield 2010 to make the installer.

What I want to know is: Is this possible and how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. The registry values are [formatted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so you can use something like this:

```
[MY_PROPERTY]
```

The location you chose is not very good. That key is used by Windows and Windows Installer internally. You can try creating your own key under SOFTWARE, for example:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\My Company\My Application
```

Comment: I'm building an installer that has a server and a client choice. When we deploy a new version of this software I want to know what choice that user made the first time, so we can skip this part of the installation.  The most logic place, to me, is the Uninstall folder since this is part of the installation and not the actual program. So is it possible to place an additional key in there? If it is possible, how do you do it in InstallShield?